# Running a GUI program on the display of a remote Linux PC via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I am connecting to remote Linux PCs via ssh, to update software and do other tasks. I want to send a notification to the remote PCs screen (eg, "Do not run program X, it is being updated now"), so the users do know what is happening.

Is there a *reverse* way for `ssh -X host` so I can connect to a remote Linux machine and run `notify-send` and it appears on the other display?

Comment: `notify-send` is just an example, right? Assuming "PC" refers to Windows, I guess `notify-send` won't work on the target machine. Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: @Arjan, nope - all remote PCs are running linux, so I will be using notify-send :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
man xhost
```

Below is a simple example that shows how to run X application remotely.

---

Add

```
xhost +local:
```

in `~/.xinitrc` of the remote mahcine,
then restart X by

```
sudo systemctl restart xdm.service
```

Then ssh into the remote machine,
try execute xclock.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows, you can take a look at the `net msg` (sp?) command from the command line. Try `net msg help`.

If Unix, there is the `wall` command, which writes to everybody's terminal (must be run as root). There is no way to connect to people's X11 server.

Answer (score 0):

try: `ssh user@hostname:~ "DISPLAY=:0 notify-send 'subject' 'message'"`

DISPLAY=:0 assumes single user, single X-session etc. If it's more involved than this, than the best thing to do is have a notification script that gets executed, instead of notify-send directly, which could go through the hoops of parsing output from 'who' to find out which terminal and X display best suits your purposes.